# how to pass a parameter to a mapreduce job in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a mapreduce job packed as a jar file (mymapreduce.jar). When running, it takes a few parameters, e.g. hadoop jar mymapreduce.jar StartClass -i input -p parameter1 -u parameter2. How can I write it as an action in an Oozie workflow file?

Answer (score 1):

Write the parameters you want to use in the oozie workflow in job.properties files as follows

```
 nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000 
hdfs://abc.xyz.yahoo.com:8020
    jobTracker=localhost:9001        
    queueName=default
    examplesRoot=map-reduce
    oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}
    inputDir=/user/input-data
    outputDir=/user/map-reduce
```

You can add configurations and the variables defined in the job.properties in the workflow.xml as following.

```
<workflow-app name='wordcount-wf' xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
    <start to='wordcount'/>
    <action name='wordcount'>
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                    <value>org.myorg.WordCount.Map</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                    <value>org.myorg.WordCount.Reduce</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>${inputDir}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>${outputDir}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to='end'/>
        <error to='end'/>
    </action>
    <kill name='kill'>
        <value>${wf:errorCode("wordcount")}</value>
    </kill/>
    <end name='end'/>
</workflow-app>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke mapreduce job using java action.The mapreduce driver class should be specified as main-class.Also you can pass required parameters as args.The parameter parsing logic should be defined in the driver class.

```
<workflow-app name="mapreduce-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">   
    <start to="mapreduce_node"/>
    <action name="mapreduce_node">
       <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <main-class>com.test.MyMapreduceDriver</main-class>
            <arg>-i</arg>
            <arg>-p</arg>
            <arg>parameter1</arg>
            <arg>-u</arg>
            <arg>parameter2</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Another option is execute it as mapreduce action. Since driver class won't be specified, You can pass required parameters as configuration properties addition to other mapreduce properties.You can access these parameters inside mapper and reducer classes using configuration object.

```
<workflow-app name='mapreduce-wf' xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
<start to='mapreduce'/>
<action name='mapreduce'>
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>p</name>
                <value>parameter1</value>
            </property>
             <property>
                <name>u</name>
                <value>parameter2</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                <value>org.myorg.WordCount.Map</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                <value>org.myorg.WordCount.Reduce</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                <value>${inputDir}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                <value>${outputDir}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </map-reduce>
    <ok to='end'/>
    <error to='end'/>
</action>
<kill name='kill'>
    <value>${wf:errorCode("mapreduce")}</value>
</kill/>
<end name='end'/>
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe specifying a mapreduce job as a java program (option 1) gives us more flexibility as we have add more logic in the driver program bu we can't if we just specify the mapper and reducer in the second option, am I right?

Comment: Yeah. With java action , you can have additional logic incorporated in driver class.